# Registry Delete Value

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, registry

I have a annoying problem.
I am trying to delete a registry value (no My Namespace) using the RegDeleteKey Value API, but with one modification.
I want the function have an absolute path as parameter.
So something like this:

```
RegDeleteKeyValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run","myValue")
```

Atm it looks like this (This one works, but has no absolute path as parameter, like it should be):

```
Private Enum RegHive
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
        HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
        HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000005
    End Enum

RegDeleteKeyValue(Reghive.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run","Myvalue")
```

I tried it to modify the function like this, so the parameters will only be the absolute path and the registryvalue.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DeleteReyKeyValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", "123")
End Sub

Public Shared Function DeleteReyKeyValue(ByVal Key As String, ByVal valueName As String) As Long
    Dim Handle As IntPtr
    Dim Hive As String = Split(Key, "\")(0)
    Select Case Hive
        Case "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"
            Handle = CType(&H80000000, IntPtr)
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"
            Handle = CType(&H80000001, IntPtr)
        Case "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
            Handle = CType(&H80000002, IntPtr)
        Case "HKEY_USERS"
            Handle = CType(&H80000003, IntPtr)
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG"
            Handle = CType(&H80000005, IntPtr)
    End Select
    Key = Key.Replace(Hive, String.Empty)
    Return RegDeleteKeyValue(Handle, Key, valueName)
End Function

<DllImport("advapi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function RegDeleteKeyValue(ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal keyName As String, ByVal valueName As String) As Long
End Function
```

When using this, nothing happens, no error, but the Registryvalue gets not deleted? ;O
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is already answered in stackoverflow

So to delete your value, you should use this code,

```
string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        // Key doesn't exist. Do whatever you want to handle
        // this case
    }
    else
    {
        key.DeleteValue("123");
    }
}
```

This would delete the value from registry. I am not sure why you are adding such complex codes.
Here is a link to msdn : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b22e94c-37a9-4be5-ad55-3d9229220194/how-to-use-add-read-change-delete-registry-keys-with-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

It has the codes for VB but still it is nearly the same for c#, you can use a online converter to convert the codes, http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick reply.
In that case a friend helped me out, code is now working.
I was only missing a + "\"
This works now:

```
 Public Shared Function DeleteReyKeyValue(ByVal Key As String, ByVal valueName As String) As Long
    Dim Handle As IntPtr
    Dim Hive As String = Split(Key, "\")(0)
    MsgBox("Hive:" & Hive)
    Select Case Hive
        Case "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"
            Handle = CType(&H80000000, IntPtr)
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"
            Handle = CType(&H80000001, IntPtr)
        Case "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
            Handle = CType(&H80000002, IntPtr)
        Case "HKEY_USERS"
            Handle = CType(&H80000003, IntPtr)
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG"
            Handle = CType(&H80000005, IntPtr)
    End Select
    Key = Key.Replace(Hive + "\", String.Empty)
    Return RegDeleteKeyValue(Handle, Key, valueName)
End Function
<DllImport("advapi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function RegDeleteKeyValue(ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal keyName As String, ByVal valueName As String) As Long
End Function
```

Credits: Rajin